# Module scoped global variable with a getter-like access function

Tags: typescript

Within the class I can have the following `_m` definition which allows me to access it via getter method while still using `obj.m` notation. I was wondering if a similar mechanism exists in regards to global members, where I could have an access via function execution but using a regular variable access syntax.

```
private _m: number;
public get m() { return this._m; }

// obj.m
```

Pseudo code regarding my question

```
// module 1
const gglob: number = 0xBAD;
export get function glob() { return gglob; }

// module 2
import { glob } from module

console.log(glob)
```

Comment: You don't need a special syntax for that just use the `alwaysStrict` compiler flag/tsconfig option. In strict mode variables are module scoped by default, no special syntax needed. Also note that your assignment isn't what you think it is: TS actually will try to parse that as a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label).

Comment: @Jared Smith My bad, it wasn't supposed to be a label, haven't had a clue that they even exists in TS :) Still the question is valid, but I don't suppose there is a mechanism in TS which would allow me to use _variable_ syntax which would trigger a function execution

Comment: You can export a const lambda function that returns the variable. With the same syntax without "get"

Comment: @Eric ah ok I didn't fully understand the question. The answer is no: there is no way to do that. Just call a function or use an object property with a getter.

Comment: @Eldar (If I understood correctly) that's defeats the purpose as I will still have to trigger it with the use of parenthesis _glob()_ instead of simply writing _glob_ to get an access

Comment: Well, then only class members can have get modifier in their functions. You can export a class instance with the value, or a class with a static getter.

Comment: @Eldar Thanks for pointing it out, I don't know why I haven't thought about it

Comment: Also, I forgot about the enums. If your value is a string or number you can also use enums. But as in your answer using a class suits your case better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I've ended up with. I wanted to have an easy access to user's *uid* (not being forced to pass it in to all functions where it has been utilised) with a simple syntax, which now can be obtained via *g.uid*

```
// module 1
export class g {
  private static _uid: string;
  public static get uid() {
    return g._uid;
  }
  static set uid(uid: string) {
    g._uid = uid;
  }
}

// module 2
await db.collection(`users/${g.uid}/ ... `);
```